# Thermal cutoff for a high current mains application

Tags: ac, mains, fuses, high-current, thermal-cutoff

I'm designing an inrush current limiter for a large rack which will under normal conditions draw ~25 A at 230 VAC. I'd like to be able to trip the current carrying live wire if the temperature in my thermistor gets too high (temperature not yet defined, likely far above 100°C). Ideally the fuse would be resettable only by manual intervention, e.g. pressing a button or by replacing the fuse with a new one.

My plan would be to mount a thermal fuse physically close to the thermistor. The thermistor would be in series with the thermal fuse.

My problem is that I can only find thermal fuses rated for carrying 25 A or above rated for carrying DC voltages up to around 60 V, not 230 VAC. These seem to be for laptop batteries and mobile phones. Do such devices exist for mains voltage and this sort of current? Or do I have to go for something more complex, like a temperature sensor linked to a relay on the live wire instead?

Comment: s/relay/contactor

Comment: Where the thermistor is mounted, which type?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, the thermistor could be two of [these](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Ametherm/AS35-5R025?qs=gt1LBUVyoHkSv4%2FvqKU1Qg%3D%3D) in series. I'd ideally put the thermal fuse between the two thermistors.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. I don't quite understand your needs, probably nothing similar exists yet. In my opinion, it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Those NTC limiters do run very hot - they rely on the rise for their resistance to drop to the point that they'll carry the full current. They're designed to operate like that, but you can find soft start boards with a relay that short them out after a couple of seconds to eliminate the steady state loss. https://www.ebay.com/itm/High-Power-40A-4000W-Soft-Start-Power-Supply-Board-for-Class-A-Amplifier/121846065770

Comment: maybe this is a dumb idea, but would 3 10A fuses in parallel work?

Comment: @PhilG yes I know, I want to short out the thermistors with a relay. The thermal fuse would be an extra safety measure to trip the current if the thermistors get too hot. I'd choose the thermal cutoff temperature to be higher than the thermistor temperature at my maximum steady state load.

Comment: @dandavis That wouldn't work because thermal fuses aren't rated to blow for a particular current, but rather temperature. If one failed, the others would enter an undefined region carrying >10A, and it's not clear what they would do at that point. They might fail open.

Comment: @Sean: don't all fuses "fail open"? And how is asking for current above the fuse rating "undefined"? They should all instantly blow, right?

Comment: @dandavis The fuse is designed to fail at a temperature, not a current. It will probably work but you can't rely on it. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/413251/84274).